# Cost for scanning nested\repeated data in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I know that the pricing for scanning data in the bigquery queries is determined by which columns are accessed.
How does this play out with nested and repeated data?
Is all the data for each record scanned? Or, does it depend on the nodes which are scanned? Are the columns in the nested data considered as each a separate column?

Thanks for any clarifications on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question - short answer is yes, BigQuery only processes the nested nodes you specify. A useful characteristic of BigQuery's columnar data storage is that nested columns can be represented as a separate column. If you don't explicitly SELECT them, the additional children field in your nested record are not processed.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I have a nested record like this:

Person : Record
  name: string
  details: Record
    detail1:string
 detail2:string
 detail3:string
Does it still scan all the detail1,detail2 detail3 even if the name doesn't meet a criteria in the query?

Comment: Example: If you run a query like "SELECT AVG(Person.detail.age) FROM [your_dataset.your_table_id] WHERE Person.name = 'john';" BigQuery will scan the all the data in columns 'Person.name' and 'Person.detail.age'. If your query lacks the WHERE clause, such as "SELECT AVG(Person.detail.age) FROM [your_dataset.your_table_id];" then BigQuery will scan only data in 'Person.detail.age'